# How to give Owin the user identity?

Tags: asp.net, iis, owin

**tl;dr**: What is the Owin equivalent of the **HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest** event?

## Background

When running an ASP.net site on IIS, the global [System.Web.HttpApplication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx) object raises an [AuthenticateRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx) event during each request.

Various http modules (such as the built-in FormsAuthentication) can attach to the event. The event handlers are called in the order in which they are registered. The first handler to set `HttpContext.Current.User` is the authentication used.

The job of the modules that are subscribed to this event is to set `HttpContext.Current.User` to to some **Principal**:

```
IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity("MBurns", "ContosoAuthentcation");
IPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);

HttpContext.Current.User = principal;
```

Once `HttpContext.Current.User` is assigned, ASP.net knows that the user has been authenticated. (And once a user has been authenticated, they are no longer anonymous).

### Any Module Can Do It

Anyone can use `web.config` to register their own `IHttpModule` with ASP.net:

**web.config**

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="MySuperCoolAuthenticationModule" type="ContosoAuthModule" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

The module is easy enough to write. You implement the lone `Init` method of the `IHttpModule` interface. For us, we add ourself as an **AuthenticateRequest** event handler:

```
public class ContosoAuthModule : IHttpModule
{
   public void Init(HttpApplication httpApplication)
   {
      // Register event handlers
      httpApplication.AuthenticateRequest += OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest;
   }
}
```

And then you can do what is needed to *authenticate* the user, and if they are a valid user, set the `HttpContext.Current.User`:

```
private void OnApplicationAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
   String username = SomeStuffToFigureOutWhoIsMakingTheRequest(request);

   if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
   {
      //I don't know who they are :(
      return;
   }

   //I know who they are, they are [username]!
   IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(username, "ContosoSuperDuperAuthentication");
   HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(identity, null);
}
```

### That's all HttpApplication

MSDN documents the various events that are thrown by **HttpApplication**, and in what order:

> [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx) *([archive.is](https://archive.fo/gfDfC))*
>
> 1. Validate the request, which examines the information sent by the browser and determines whether it contains potentially malicious markup. For more information, see [ValidateRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.pagessection.validaterequest.aspx)<sup>[a](https://archive.fo/WSgUq)</sup> and [Script Exploits Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1sw53ds.aspx)<sup>[a](https://archive.fo/ExzzV)</sup>.
> 2. Perform URL mapping, if any URLs have been configured in the [UrlMappingsSection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.urlmappingssection.aspx)<sup>[a](https://archive.fo/pkRhv)</sup> section of the Web.config file.
> 3. Raise the [BeginRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.beginrequest.aspx) event.
> 4. **Raise the [AuthenticateRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authenticaterequest.aspx)<sup>[a](https://archive.fo/JTmq1)</sup> event.**
> 5. Raise the [PostAuthenticateRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthenticaterequest.aspx) event.
> 6. Raise the [AuthorizeRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.authorizerequest.aspx) event.
> 7. Raise the [PostAuthorizeRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.postauthorizerequest.aspx) event.
> 8. Raise the [ResolveRequestCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.resolverequestcache.aspx) event.

And that's all great when it's ASP.net and **HttpApplication**. Everything's well understood, easy enough to explain (in the half-screenful above), and works.

But **HttpApplication** is old and busted.

### Owin is the new hotness

Everything is supposed to be Owin now. **HttpApplication** lives in `System.Web`. People want to be isolated from `System.Web`. They want this *thing* called **Owin** to be in charge now.

To further that goal, they (i.e. any new ASP.net MCV, web-forms, or SignalR web-site) disables the authentication system of ASP.net completely:

```
<system.web> 
   <authentication mode="None" />
</system.web>
```

So no more **HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest** event. :(

### What is the Owin equivalent?

What is the Owin equivalent of **HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest**?

It's safe to say that no matter where my code is called from, my job is still to set `HttpContext.Current.User` to an identity.

Is it safe to say that no matter where my code is called form, my job is still to set `HttpContext.Current.User` to an identity?

What is the Owin equivalent of **HttpApplication.AuthenticateRequest**?

### Attempt that doesn't work

Nothing of it is ever called:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.Owin.Extensions;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Principal;

[assembly: OwinStartup("AnyStringAsLongAsItsNotBlank", typeof(BasicAuthOwin))]
public class BasicAuthOwin
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("They did their best, shoddily-iddly-iddly-diddly");
            OnAuthenticateRequest(context);
            return next.Invoke();
        });
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);

        app.Run(context =>
            {
                return context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello world");
            });
    }

    private void OnAuthenticateRequest(IOwinContext context)
    {
        var request = context.Request;
        String username = SomeStuffToFigureOutWhoIsMakingTheRequest(request);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(username))
        {
            //I don't know who they are :(
            return;
        }

        //I know who they are, they are [username]!
        IIdentity identity = new GenericIdentity(username, "ContosoSuperDuperOwinAuthentication");
        context.Authentication.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
    }

    private string SomeStuffToFigureOutWhoIsMakingTheRequest(IOwinRequest request)
    {
        //if ((System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.GetTimestamp % 3) == 0)
        //  return "";

        return "MBurns";
    }
}
```

Comment: have you ever solved this problem? I am interested in very same thing.

Comment: @deezg I never did. It wasn't a big deal, because we all know that IIS and **System.Web** isn't going anywhere. I just commented out the  `authentication mode="None"` setting in web.config (and gave Owin a gentle *"that's nice dear"* pat on the head)

Comment: :) Thanks for your response. I did pretty much the same for now.

Comment: Have you tried lately? It seems to work for me, this application: http://pastebin.com/mP4ZSxGQ displays "Hello world MBurns" on a browser (I changed the WriteAsync output to use HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the blog post from this website [Jwt Authentication in ASP.NET WEB API AND MVC](http://techcerberus.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/jwt-in-aspnet-web-api-and-mvc.html). It explains how to solve to issue of "Authorization has been denied for this request" using OWIN.

**The JWTHandler class**

```
public static void OnAuthenticateRequest(IOwinContext context)
        {
            var requestHeader = context.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");
            int userId = Convert.ToInt32(JwtDecoder.GetUserIdFromToken(requestHeader).ToString());
            var identity = new GenericIdentity(userId.ToString(), "StakersClubOwinAuthentication");
            //context.Authentication.User = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

            var token = requestHeader.StartsWith("Bearer ") ? requestHeader.Substring(7) : requestHeader;
            var secret = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("jwtKey");
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = ValidateToken(
                token,
                secret,
                true
                );
            context.Authentication.User = (ClaimsPrincipal) Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            //if (HttpContext.Current != null)
            //{
            //    HttpContext.Current.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
            //}
        }
```

**The Startup class**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var config = new HttpConfiguration();

            app.Use((context, next) =>
            {
                JwtAuthHandler.OnAuthenticateRequest(context); //the new method
                return next.Invoke();
            });
            app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);            
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);//Remove or comment the config.MessageHandlers.Add(new JwtAuthHandler()) section it would not be triggered on execution.


            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }



    }
```